# How to align label and textbox on sameline in angular formly?

Tags: angular-formly

How to align `Label` and `Textbox` on same line in Angular Formly? By default the `Label` is placed above an `Input`. How to align it `in-line` with the input?

Comment: can you show me sample code of your label and textbox

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `bootstrap templates` ? If yes is [this](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/bootstrap-specific/bootstrap-horizontal) what you are looking for?

If you are not using `bootstrap templates` then you can find the example there on how its done and make your own.

**REMEMBER**: Even though sometimes there is space to put the label on the left of the input (so it's on the same line) there are cases where it HAS to be above the input so that it will fit on screen (be responsive) and give a good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

In know that it is late. But i can add something that works for me

Your type must be inline not just input or stacked-input:

```
 type: 'inline-input'
```